# Populate list in Django using view

Tags: python, html, django, python-3.x

I have the following function to read news headlines into a Python list:

```py
import requests


def us_news_articles():
    url = 'https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&apiKey=###
    source = requests.get(url)
    data = source.json()
    us_news_articles_list = []
    for article in data['articles']:
        us_news_articles_list.append(article)
    return us_news_articles_list
```

This function works, and I've verified it.

Now I want to be able to use this to populate HTML `li` items

I have the following views built:

```py
def viz(request):
    return render(request, 'resume/viz.html')

class USNewsArticles(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'viz'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = {
            'articles': us_news_articles(),
        }
        return context
```

My URL looks like this

```py
path('viz/', views.viz, name='viz')
```

And in my HTML file, I have the following:

```html
            <ul>
            {% for article in articles %}
              <li>{{ article.title }}</li>
                <ul>
                  <li>{{ article.description }}</li>
                </ul>
            {% endfor %}
            </ul>
```

However, when I deploy the website, I get no list. I believe it's an issue with the view, but I am not well-versed enough in understand views and functions to understand why it will not populate the `li` items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your URLs are routed to your `viz` view, which just renders an empty template (`viz.html`). I think what you meant to do is this:

```
class USNewsArticles(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'resume/viz.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = {
            'articles': us_news_articles(),
        }
        return context
```

And your URL:

```
path('viz/', USNewsArticles.as_view())
```

`TemplateView` is a helper where you specify the template file directly, and it supplies the appropriate `GET` handler. - no need for an intermediate `def myview` function. In fact, the beauty of Class-Based Views is it writes a lot of the boilerplate for you. Unless you are customizing the behavior, you generally don't have to write methods that return `Responses` by hand.

Comment: That worked! Just had to import the class into my URLs. Follow up question, if I want to write multiple different API calls, can I pass those new classes into the same context? For example, the one above is US News, but let's say I did a new API call UK news.

Comment: In that case I would suggest passing the `country` in your url path, and changing the template context depending on the value.

Comment: e.g,, `path('viz/<country>', views.viz, name='viz')`